# what gwt graphics library shall be used for client side stock charting development?

Tags: gwt, graphics

I am just starting gwt development and would like to know what is the right way to create client side stock charting with gwt.

I've checked on highchart, which looks good but it is not gwt based.

gwt-graphics library seems the right one but not very active.

Google gwt-visualization seems not allow modification on top to support candlestick and other complicated requirements.

gchart seems not only support simple line charts and not extensible to candlestick easily.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any GWT specific charting libraries. However there are some GWT wrapper for existing Javascript Charting libraries:

- [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/)
- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) ([Protovis-GWT](http://code.google.com/p/choosel/wiki/ProtovisGWT))
- [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) ([Raphael-gwt)](http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/)

I personally use google visualization and for simple charts (Barchart, etc) it is fine. I also like dygraphs because it has some neat features (zooming, stacking, etc). 
In the end you can always write your own GWT wrapper for an existing javascript charting library.

Comment: thank you for the information. Seems the quickest way is to use highchart with the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

[raphael4gwt](http://code.google.com/p/raphael4gwt/) support many chart types (http://g.raphaeljs.com/).

Demo (w java sources online): http://cancerbero.vacau.com/gwt/graphael4gwtGallery/?test=bar2

Getting started: http://code.google.com/p/raphael4gwt/wiki/GRaphael4GwtGettingStarted

hope it helps somebody